# Overriding some overloads in a derived class but not others

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, virtual

I'd expect this to work:

```
template <typename T> class MyBaseClass
{
public:
    MyBaseClass();

    virtual ~MyBaseClass();

    void DoSomething(const T& myClass);  
         // Implemented in .cpp file

    virtual void DoSomething(int n, const T& myClass);  
                 // Implemented in .cpp file
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass<int>
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething(int n, const int& myInt);  
                 // Implemented in .cpp file
};
```

...and elsewhere in my code:

```
int i;
MyDerivedClass myClass;
myClass.DoSomething(i);
```

However, it does not; instead, it fails to compile with an error saying (in the case of Visual C++)

```
error C2660: 'int::DoSomething' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

...even though there manifestly *is* a version of DoSomething, declared in the base class, that *does* take just one argument. The error goes away if I comment out the redefinition of DoSomething with *two* arguments from the derived class.

What subtle C++ rule have I falled foul of, and is there an elegant way to work around this?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong with my 1st comment.

Comment: please edit your code, `myBaseClass` needs capital initial letter and `int MyDerivedClass` needs to be `class MyDerivedClass`

Comment: My guess is it's some intricacy of function lookup. The function is found in derived, and not looked further; only then overload resolution is tried (within derived) which fails (derived doesn't declare that signature). Cf. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: BTW, implementation of `template <typename T> void MyBaseClass<T>::DoSomething(const T& myClass)` should go in header...

Comment: @TemplateRex, you're quite right; I've done so.

Comment: @Jarod42, you're quite right - I was too lazy to compose an ad-hoc implementation within the declaration, and tried to cover my tracks with a comment that turned out to be inaccurate. I have nowhere to hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method in C++ shadows *all* methods of the super class which have the same name. In your example

```
virtual void DoSomething(int n, const int& myInt);
```

in the derived class shadows

```
void DoSomething(const T& myClass);
```

in the base class, so the latter method is not visible when working with an object of the derived type.

This behaviour is quite different to other languages like Java where a method does not shadow other methods with the same name but different signatures and might feel a bit counter intuitive at first. The reason for this is simply the name lookup rules of C++: Once a name is found in a scope, further scopes are not considered. In your example, the compiler finds `DoSomething(const T&)` in your derived class and stops looking for further methods in the super class.

There is a simple remedy: To make all `DoSomething` methods visible again, use the `using` directive in your derived class:

```
using MyBaseClass<int>::DoSomething;
```

The `using` directive makes the methods that were shadowed visible again by pulling them into the scope of the derived class. Now, name lookup will find the correct `DoSomething(int, const int&)` method in the scope of the derived class.

Comment: Or calling the shaded method directly: `myClass.MyBaseClass::DoSomething(i);`

Comment: @icepack: Your suggestion works for this scenario but is usually not what you want, because it will disable `vtable` lookup for virtual methods. So, if `DoSomething(int)` was virtual, your call would always call `MyBaseClass::DoSomething(int)` instead of an overriding `DoSomething(int)` method in a potential subclass!

Comment: Of course, that's why I prefixed it explicitly :) I think it would've been pretty confusing if explicit prefix would allow polymorphic behavior

Comment: @icepack: But this is not what you usually want. Here, the problem is simply method shadowing. You solve it by removing polymorphism from the called method which is a totally orthogonal thing.

Comment: Thank you; simply adding the 'using' directive on the line before declaring my overriding overload did the trick. As you say, it's counter-intuitive and rather irritating but at least the workaround is painless.